# Why isn't my animated background taking up the whole screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to put an animated interactive screen in my html website but the animation only takes up a little bit of space to the left of the question container. What's a fix for this?

here's my html index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
   <title>Quiz App</title>
</head>
<body>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="question-container" class="hide">
      <div id="question">Question</div>
      <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
        <button class="btn">Answer 1</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 2</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 3</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 4</button>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="container1">
      <div id="startmsgcontainer" class="hide"></div>
        <div id="startmsg">Adventure Into The Human Immune System</div>
        </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">Start!</button>
      <button id="next-btn" class="next-btn btn hide">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="uni.png" alt="image">
  </div>
 </div> 
  <div id="particles-js"></div>
  <script src="particles.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: the particle stuff is what I named my animated background since it's a bunch of particles

Here's my css

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: cursive,
    'Times New Roman', Times, serif
  }
  
  :root {
    --hue-neutral: 0;
    --hue-wrong: 0;
    --hue-correct: 145;
  }

  body {
    --hue: var(--hue-neutral);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 20%);
  }

  body.correct {
    --hue: var(--hue-correct);
  }
  
  body.wrong {
    --hue: var(--hue-wrong);
  }
  
  .container {
    width: 800px;
    max-width: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
  }
  
  .btn-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
    gap: 10px;
    margin: 20px 0;
  }
  
  .btn {
    --hue: var(--hue-neutral);
    border: 1px solid hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 30%);
    background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 50%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
  }
  
  .btn:hover {
    border-color: black;
  }
  
  .btn.correct {
    --hue: var(--hue-correct);
    color: black;
  }
  
  .btn.wrong {
    --hue: var(--hue-wrong);
  }
  
  .next-btn {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }

  .start-btn {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    --hue: 245;
  }

  .container1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: xx-large;
    padding: 40px 40px;

  }
  
  .controls {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 
  }
  
  .hide {
    display: none;
  }

  .wrapper { 
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
  }

.particles-js {
  background-size: 100vh;
  background-position: 100vw;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

I need everything to stay the same and send the particles to the background of the entire html site. I appreciate any help because I am very lost. (the last part is my attempt to send it to the back but it didn't work)

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @hev1 what does "reproducible example" mean? Sorry, I'm new to programming so I don't know much jargon

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @hev1 the animated screen is only a small window to left of the question container, I want it to be in the background of the whole website and I'm pretty sure the problem is that I don't know how to define the animated background as a container and send it to the back since the question container is not centered on the page. Is that enough?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/particlesvue-20-kwsl6 Try this sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using particles.js with Vue but here's how I change the size:
[image: Example of how to change width and height]

Change the width and height of the containing div and then refresh. I thought it wasn't working at first as it stretches the particles out but I guess it needs to re-render them.

Also, if you're looking to send them to the back, set `position: absolute; z-index: 0`. You'll have to set `z-index: 1` of whatever's in front of them as well.

Just noticed, you're using a class selector instead of an id selector in your CSS: `.particles-js`, should be `#particles-js`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a codePen for your code samples? It's easier to see what the issue is from there. Also, add a comment to the div enclosing the animation.